# Как с помощью Laravel eloquent получить связаные данные таблиц?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть четыре таблицы `characters`, `locations`, `character_classes` и `friends`.
friends - хранит данные  в виде пары id персонажей из таблицы characters

Как зная id персонажа максимально простым способом получить список друзей состоящий из столбцов  `characters.name`, `characters.gender`, `characters.level_id`, `characters.update_at`, `locations.name`, `character_classes.name`?

Пытался чудить с джойнами, но максимум что получилось так это вытянуть список друзей персонажа состоящий исключительно из данных таблицы characters, без связных данных из других таблиц.

Я так понимаю тут нужно грамотно прописать связи в моделях. Из того что уже создал это связи для 
Characters

```
public function characterClass(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CharacterClass::class);
}

public function location(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
}
```

и Location

```
public function characters()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Character::class);
}
```

В миграции ключи для таблицы `characters`выглядят так

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');

        $table->uuid('location_id');
        $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->unsignedInteger('character_class_id');
        $table->foreign('character_class_id')->references('id')->on('character_classes')->onDelete('restrict');
```

для таблицы `character_classes`

```
$table->uuid('starting_location_id');
        $table->foreign('starting_location_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('locations')
            ->onDelete('restrict');
```

Больше никаких ключей не добавлял.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите ключи, а то не совсем понятны `id`. И Опишите поля таблицы друзей.

Answer (score 1):

Удалось получить нужные данные таким образом. Если есть варианты получше, буду рад посмотреть)

```
Character::rightJoin(
        'friends',
        function ($join) {
            $join->on('friends.id_friend_one', '=', 'characters.id')
                ->orOn('friends.id_friend_two', '=', 'characters.id');
        }
    )
        ->where(
            function ($query) use ($id) {
                $query->where('friends.id_friend_one', '=', $id)
                    ->whereRaw('friends.id_friend_two = characters.id');
            }
        )
        ->orWhere(
            function ($query) use ($id) {
                $query->whereRaw('friends.id_friend_one = characters.id')
                    ->where('friends.id_friend_two', '=', $id);
            }
        )
        ->with(['location:id,name','characterClass:id,name'])
        ->skip($skip)
        ->take(15)
        ->get(['characters.id','characters.name','characters.gender','characters.location_id','characters.character_class_id','characters.level_id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не рекомендую использовать сырые запросы к бд это плохая практика, работа по отношениям во фреймворке легкая и непринужденная

Если я верно понял условия задачи и все отношения то вот ваше решение (внимательно названия методов в модели приведены к единственному числу и соответственно меняется вызов):

```
//связи для модели User
public function character(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Character::class);
}

//связи для модели Character
public function character_class(){
  return $this->belongsTo(СharacterClass::class);
}

//связи для модели СharacterClass
public function location(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
}


$user = User::find($id_friend_one);

$user->character->name;
$user->character->gender;
$user->character->level_id;
$user->character->update_at;
$user->character->character_class->name;
$user->character->character_class->location->name;
```